# .htaccess & mod_rewrite to flat URLs using different criteria

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I use .htaccess & mod_rewrite to perform the following URL rewrite?

This page: `http://mysite.com/page.php?id=2387281`

Becomes: `http://mysite.com/[criteria1]/[criteria2]`

I have my database set up so the primary key is an ID number, but I want my URLs to include two fields related to that ID, but not the actual ID itself.

How can I accomplish this?

An example using what my database structure looks like

```
Row 1: ID: 234 ; CRITERIA1: Food ; CRITERIA2: Steak

mysite.com/page.php?id=234 --> mysite.com/food/steak
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't rewrite data that isn't there - you can't get a database ID that wasn't in the URL in first place.

You would have to do something like:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/(.*) page.php?criteria1=$1&criteria2=$2
```

...and run a SELECT on the database at the top of the script to get the ID based on the criteria...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM table WHERE criteria1 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['criteria1'])."' AND criteria2 = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['criteria2'])."'");
```

Comment: That's what I was attempting, but, although **extremely** unlikely, it is possible for c1 & c2 to be the same with different ids.

I'm going to give it one more shot

Comment: How do you mean? Why would they end up being the same? And do you mean that the two criteria would be the same, or there would be more than one row with the same criteria?

Comment: The two criteria in each row could potentially be the same with different ids. Ex:

Row 1: ID 334 CRITERIA1 ABC CRITERIA2 DEF
Row 2: ID 434 CRITERIA1 ABC CRITERIA2 DEF

I think that's how I'm going to do it though because that'd be very rare.

I'm now running into a different problem which is that all of my links get changed. If I go to http://mysite.com it redirects to a strange url with other slashes.

How do I make it so the url structure is strictly for page.php??

Comment: It really depends how you are generating/specifying your links - can you give some examples of what should happen and is happening? And with regards to the duplicated rows, I would suggest you structure your application in such a way that it cannot happen - you could add a sanity check to the database itself by adding a unique index that covers both criteria columns.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. Going to rethink the layout. The problem with the other links was because I was changing levels.

Thanks for your help, I'm going to rethink my structure and post here again if necessary.

Comment: Yeah, still having trouble with the levels. What's the best way to reference all my other stuff in the code (styles.css, includes/config.php, etc) so it'll work from http://localhost/mysite/ as well as http://mysite.com?

Comment: If you place all your external resources (css, js, images etc) in a directory that will never appear as a criteria name, then you can add another rewrite rule for it, e.g. `RewriteRule ^(.*)myuniquedirectoryname(.*)/([^/])$ myuniquedirectoryname/$3 [L]` should do the job, and will rewrite any request that contains `myuniquedirectoryname` to `myuniquedirectoryname/file.ext`, and drop any other information. Place that BEFORE the rule in the answer!

Comment: I just moved the files up into my root folder on localhost to mirror how it is in my real host and everything works perfectly now. Thanks for your help, guys

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your right, which I *think* I do, then you won't use the id in the url at all.  Have the modrewrite rule be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)$ http://site.com/page.php?col1=$1&col2=$2 [L]
```

Then in page.php, I presume you used to have a query like:

```
select * from table where id=123
```

Just replace that query with:

```
"select * from table where col1='".$_GET['col1']."' and col2='".$_GET['col2']."'"
```

Obviously make sure the sanitize your input to prevent sql injection.

The only thing you need to ensure is that the tuple of col1 and col2 are unique and don't return more than 1 value.

So in this example, the id number is never seen in the url and actually is never used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that with mod_rewrite/.htaccess. Instead, you should use php to [connect to mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ddws/) and load the data, then [redirect](http://phpprogrammingguide.blogspot.com/2005/11/php-header-301-redirect-moved.html) to the appropriate page.

Comment: It's essentially what wordpress does, but I'm not using wordpress. Is that how they do it?

The point of these links is for SEO and user-friendly navigation, I don't think 301 redirects would accomplish those goals.

Comment: Then use a different [status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection).